# Positioning a div with image to the center of the page

Tags: html, css

I have created a div tag with image in it , but I cannot force this div to display everything in center of the page :

```css
#mydiv {
position: absolute;
height: auto;
width: 1000px;
min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive-full-background-image.css">

</head>

<body>
<div id="mydiv"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/960x461/FF9900/fff" width="960" height="461" /></div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

lover
You should use % because then the image while stay in the middle on different screen resolutions.

```
#yourdiv{
position: absolute;
height: auto;
width: 30%; ( % = the with of your image)
margin-left: 35%; ( 1/2 of % left)
margin-right: 35%; ( 1/2 of % left)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it only needs to be horizontally centered, it can be as simple as.

http://jsfiddle.net/g4we9b7x/

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
#mydiv {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If it needs to be both centered, read this - [how to center an element horizontally and vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19461564/483779)

Overall, this is the easiest for centering both - http://jsfiddle.net/g4we9b7x/1/

```
#mydiv {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: Thanks , now this is center alignment , but how can  I move it to exact middle of the screen ? both horizontal and vertical

Comment: @Mc.Lover did you see the last bit in the answer? just follow that link.

Answer (score 1):

try `text-align:center`

```css
#mydiv {
    background:orange;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="mydiv">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300" width="460px" height="461px" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to put the image in the centre of the div? Use `text-align:center;`

Below I have replaced the width to 100% and made the image smaller to illustrate `text-align:center;`

```css
#mydiv {
position: absolute;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
min-height: 50px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive-full-background-image.css">

</head>

<body>
<div id="mydiv"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/96x46/FF9900/fff"  /></div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a difficult task depending on the rest of the layout. better read this article: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Comment: What about the Image ? not whole div

Answer (score 0):

```
position:absolute:
width:1000px;
height:500px;
top:50%;
margin-top:-250px; <!-- minus half the height of the box -->
laft:50%;
margin-left:-500px; <!-- minus half the width of the box -->
```

http://codepen.io/o0nico0o/pen/RNvzKy